# Accessing variables from IIFE

Tags: javascript

I have the following closure:

```
var Container = (function () {
   var variable;
   var changeVariable = function () {
       variable = 5;
   };
   return {
       variable: variable,
       changeVariable: changeVariable
   };
})();

Container.changeVariable();
console.log(Container.variable);
```

The result is undefined, unless I set variable as:

`Container.variable = 5`

Why is that so? What's the difference? How should I do this properly?

Comment: You've returned the variable by **value**, not by reference. The variable is updated inside the IIFE, but the returned value is not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why is that so?

JavaScript assigns by value.

`variable = 5;` assigns the value `5` to the variable `variable`.

`variable: variable,` assigns the value of `variable` (**at the time** the code runs) to the property `variable`. It does not create a reference to the variable called `variable`.

When you later change the value of the variable called `variable`, you don't change the value of the property called `variable`.

> How should I do this properly?

Create an object. Store the object locally. Manipulate that object. Return that object.

Forget about having the variable called `variable` entirely.

```js
var container = (function() {

  var self = {
    variable: undefined,
    changeVariable: changeVariable
  };

  function changeVariable() {
    self.variable = 5;
  }

  return self;
})();

container.changeVariable();
console.log(container.variable);
```

(Aside: Convention reserves identifiers beginning with capital letters for constructor functions. I've renamed `Container` to follow that convention).

Answer (score 2):

Use a getter:

```
return {
   get variable() { return variable; },
   changeVariable: changeVariable
};
```

Comment: Don't just dump code without explaining how and why it works.